# I cant access an object key in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, key

Working in a react component that receives props from a parent component. Props are static (no need to check for updates) and received OK. The prop is an array of objects. This array is logged OK in the console, even a single array item array[x] is logged properly to the console, BUT if I want to access a specific key such as "eventDate", it logs "CAN NOT READ eventDate of undefined".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// AUX COMP
import Moment from 'react-moment'; // --> https://momentjs.com/
import moment from 'moment';

// SERVICE API
import Calculations from '../../services/Calculations';


export default class EventsGraphic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user              : this.props.userID,
      patientId         : this.props.patID,

      patientsEvents    : this.props.events,
      eventsSorted      : [],
      firstEventDate    : '',

      timeLineDays      : 60,
    }
  }

_eventsGraphicData(){

   let pEvts = [...this.props.events];
   let eventsSorted  = Calculations.sortByEventDate(pEvts); 

    console.log('pEvts', pEvts);
    console.log('eventsSorted[0]', eventsSorted[0]);
        // this prints to the console the object in the index 0 of the array correctly ONE OF THE KEYS IS eventDate
        console.log('eventsSorted[0].eventDate = ', eventsSorted[0].eventDate);
       // THIS LOGS "CAN NOT READ PROPERTY eventDate OF UNDEFINED ?!?!?!


return eventsSorted

  }

render() {

  return (


  <div className="events-chart">

    <p>DATA GOES HERE</p>

  </div>


   );
 };
};
```

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY6jz.png)

Comment: Please provide an example of the data and screenshots of the console / the log output.

Comment: Can you show results of above console.log ?

Comment: this is the log of eventsSorted[0]: {
  action: "adsfasdf"
  clinicObservation: "adfadgasd"
detonation: "asdfasdf"
  duration: "22"
  eventDate: "2018-11-27"
  eventId: "DPSrnSudDfNfjnygNs92"
  fever: "38,2"
  minSaturation: "82"
  patientId: "vkNbkuqDO8GDVGXrIzGz"
  startTime: "02:22"
}
But if I try to acces any ky e.g  eventDate, then I get the error

Comment: @FelixKling screenshots shared

Comment: Strange! Have you tried another key? And your code calls eventsSorted[0].eventDate 2 times in 2 console.log, Is that typo?

Comment: Yes I tried with other keys and its the same story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Stringified object in sortedEvent not Object and of course received undefined on key.